# What are the coloured bands in this "Pale Blue Dot" picture?

Tags: space, visible-light

You can see Earth in the right most band in this image:

[image]

What are these bands doing in space?! Can somebody please explain the coloured bands in this image?

Comment: Given the possibility that this is an optical effect in the lenses used to take the image, a link to the original image would help. For that matter it might help to convince the commentariet around here to look for a physics explanation outside of the optics, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the wikipedia page about the photo: [The Pale Blue Dot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Blue_Dot)

> The light band over Earth is an artifact of sunlight scattering in the camera's optics, resulting from the small angle between the Earth and the Sun.